# How to select the last element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to select all last messages after each "Hello" in css?

Not using JavaScript.

```css
.my {
  text-align: right;
}

.my:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="me">Hello</p>

<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my">last message</p>

<p class="me">Hello</p>
<p class="me">Hello</p>

<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my">last message</p>
```

It should be:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SkvS.png)

Comment: do you render the messages dynamically?

Comment: yes it's a chat

Comment: Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: Add another CSS class for last message

Comment: You can't with that HTML structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to wrap each group of `.my` messages in a container to make use of `:last-of-type` or apply a specific modifier class to the last message:

```css
.my {
  text-align: right;
}

.my.last {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="me">Hello</p>

<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my last">last message</p>

<p class="me">Hello</p>
<p class="me">Hello</p>

<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my">message</p>
<p class="my last">last message</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I have a solution for you, you need to reverse your messages then css magic can happen:

```css
.chat-messages {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.my {
  text-align: right;
}

.my:first-of-type, .me + .my {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-messages">
  <p class="my">last message</p>
  <p class="my">message</p>
  <p class="my">message</p>
  <p class="me">Hello</p>
  <p class="me">Hello</p>
  <p class="my">last message</p>
  <p class="my">message</p>
  <p class="my">message</p>
  <p class="my">message</p>
  <p class="me">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's worth to note that new messages have to be inserted e.g. as `chatMsgs.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p class="me / my">...</p>');` and not at the _bottom_ of the _parent element_.